# How do I make columns hidden by default in MaterialTable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

my MaterialTable has a lot of columns and some of them are not necessarily needed to be displayed at all times. I want to make them hidden unless selected by user

I tried adding

```
hide: true
```

property to the column but it didn't do anything

Code sample with `hidden` :

```
      {
    title: 'Department', field: 'department', filtering: false, editable: 'never',hidden: true,
    cellStyle: {
      width: 250,
      minWidth: 250,
      border: '1px solid #CCC',
      padding: 0
    },
    headerStyle: {
      width: 250,
      minWidth: 250
    }
  },
  { title: 'Owner', field: 'owner', filtering: false, editable: 'never', hidden: true},
  { title: 'Responsible', field: 'responsible', filtering: false, editable: 'never', hidden: true },
```

These 3 columns still show up in my table

More info on my question:

- My app doesn't use TypeScript, only JS and Atlassian SDK (Java)
- I am not allowed to rewrite/redesign the app
  My code:

  ```
   const [state, setState] = React.useState({
   columns: [
     { title: 'Module', field: 'module', lookup: dynamicLookupObject, editable: 'never' },
     { title: 'Key', field: 'key', filtering: false, editable: 'never', render: rowData => <a href={rowData.key}>{rowData.key}</a>},
     {
       title: 'Summary', field: 'summary', filtering: false, editable: 'never',
       cellStyle: {
         width: 250,
         minWidth: 250,
         border: '1px solid #CCC',
         padding: 0
       },
       headerStyle: {
         width: 250,
         minWidth: 250
       }
     },
     { title: 'Task', field: 'task', filtering: false, editable: 'never', render: rowData => <a href={'rowData.task}>{rowData.task}</a> },
     { title: 'Team', field: 'team', lookup: { },
     {
       title: 'Department', field: 'department', filtering: false, editable: 'never',
       cellStyle: {
         width: 250,
         minWidth: 250,
         border: '1px solid #CCC',
         padding: 0
       },
       headerStyle: {
         width: 250,
         minWidth: 250
       }
     },
     { title: 'Owner', field: 'owner', filtering: false, editable: 'never' },
     { title: 'Responsible', field: 'responsible', filtering: false, editable: 'never' },
     { title: 'Status', field: 'status', filtering: false, editable: 'never' },
  ```

. . .

---

```
  return (
<div>

  <MaterialTable

    // //count total of "next month evaluation"
    components={{
      Body: props => <MTableBody {...props} onFilterChanged={(columnId, value) => {
        totalOfTeamEval = 0
        props.onFilterChanged(columnId, value);
        value = value
        console.log(value)
        var arrData = state.data
        var filteredData = arrData.filter(function (item) { return item.module == value; });
        var totalOfTeamEval = 0

        });
        setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, totalOfTeamEval }), () => resolve());



      }} />

    }}
    title="IDEA report"
    columns={state.columns}
    data={state.data}
    icons={{ Edit: () => <EditIcon style={{ fontSize: 15, padding: 0 }} /> }}
    editable={{
```

. . .

Comment: I think your question was down-voted because you didn't supply enough information. Try adding in code snippets, and more detail to help the community better answer your question. =]

Comment: followup on my question: I managed to hide columns with `hidden: true` property but now I cannot enable these columns as they don't show up in "add or remove columns" menu. I need these to be hidden by default but avaliable for displaying if user chooses them

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using a basic Material UI (MUI) Table, then I think what you are really after is the `MUI Data Grid` which comes with functionality for toggling columns.

Checkout the docs for Data Grid [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/)

Using MUI Data Grid you can update the column visibility by setting `columns.columnVisibilityModel` prop for the `initialState` on the `DataGrid` component

```
<DataGrid
  columns={...}
  rows={...}
  initialState={{
    // other initial state values...
    columns: {
      columnVisibilityModel: {
        // Initially hide the id and status columns
        id: false,
        status: false
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

The `columnVisibilityModel` has a TypeScript type like `Record<GridKey, boolean>` where the `GridKey` is one of the `field` value in your column definition.

Docs for column visibility [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/)

Here is a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-ans-mui-data-grid-hide-cols-rm5qds) with the above code snippet in action

Hope this helps!

Update: **Adding answer based on OP's potential use of [Material Table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started) library**

If you are using the Material Table library then you just have use `column.hidden` instead. The `hide` prop doesn't exist in that library's [column config](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/b26e2f715abb2217f0d14e1efb15c6367fe12de1/types/index.d.ts#L188C6-L188C6).

Try this:

```
hidden: true
```

In context it would look like this:

```
<MaterialTable
  columns={[
    { title: "Adı", field: "name" },
    { title: "Soyadı", field: "surname" },
    { title: "Doğum Yılı", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
    {
      title: "Doğum Yeri",
      field: "birthCity",
      lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" },

      // This is what you want
      hidden: true
    },
  ]}
  data={[{ name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }]}
  title="Demo Title"
/>
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm using MaterialTable and on the top it has a "Show columns" menu where I can select which are displayed. I just want some of them to not be displayed when users open the page. Unfortunately I do not have permisson to rewrite the app using DataGrid.

Comment: @ihateapachegroovy Are you using this package -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-table ? Maybe that's the missing piece of the puzzle here.

Comment: Yes version is "material-table": "^1.68.0"

Comment: Cool. I updated the answer to include a solution for using that library. =]

Comment: thanks but it still didn't work for me. I've updated my question with new info

Answer (score 0):

1. First, make sure you have installed the material-table package. If not, you can install it using npm or yarn:
   npm install material-table or yarn add material-table
2. Next, in your React component where you are using MaterialTable, define the column configuration and set the hidden property for the columns you want to hide by default.

For example:
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

```
const MyTable = () => {
  const columns = [
    { title: 'ID', field: 'id', hidden: true }, // This column will be hidden by default
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age', hidden: true }, // This column will be hidden by default
    { title: 'Country', field: 'country' },
  ];

  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 30, country: 'USA' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 25, country: 'Canada' },
    // Add more data here
  ];

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      title="My Table"
    />
  );
};

export default MyTable;
```

In this example, the ID and Age columns will be hidden by default when the table is rendered. If you need to show or hide columns dynamically based on user interactions or application logic, you can also use the hidden property in conjunction with state management to control the column visibility at runtime.

By setting the hidden property for specific columns, you can ensure that those columns remain hidden by default when the MaterialTable component is rendered.

Comment: sorry this doesn't work for me. my code:

      { title: 'Module', field: 'module', lookup: dynamicLookupObject, editable: 'never', hidden: true},
      {
        title: 'Department', field: 'department', filtering: false, editable: 'never',hidden: true
      },
      { title: 'Owner', field: 'owner', filtering: false, editable: 'never', hidden: true},
      { title: 'Responsible', field: 'responsible', filtering: false, editable: 'never', hidden: true },

still these columns are present when the page loads